# Find the angles between two solids

Tags: geometry, angle, solid-geometry, orientation

I have 2 solids (A and B) and I need to find the three angles between their x, y, and z axes. If I calculate the geometrical center of the two solids (Ax, Ay, Az and Bx, By, Bz), is it correct to calculates the angles between their axes as follow?

Thank you

$\Delta x = Ax - Bx$

$\Delta y = Ay - By$

$\Delta z = Az - Bz$

$\angle x = a\tan 2(\Delta x, \sqrt{\Delta y^2 + \Delta z^2})$

$\angle y = a\tan 2(\Delta y, \sqrt{\Delta x^2 + \Delta z^2})$

$\angle z = a\tan 2(\Delta z, \sqrt{\Delta x^2 + \Delta y^2})$

Answer (score 1):

*Angle between solids* has no meaning. We can have an intersection angle between two planes.

Comment: Hi Narasimham, thank you. Of course I expressed myself badly. How can I calculate the angles between the planes defined by their axes ?

Comment: Define lines of intersection. Find angle between normals of two planes (at a time) at any convenient point on a line of intersection.

Comment: Thank you again for your time @Narasimham. So, is my attempt correct? Or I totally missed the point here ?

Comment: See, if it makes sense in some way I would go that way else I choose all *pairs* of planes.

Comment: Thank you for your clear and detailed answer @Narasimham. Have a nice day